# Broken polygons in levelplot using ggplot stat_density_2d

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon, density-plot

Creating a levelplot using `ggplot`'s `stat_density_2d` I get "*broken*" polygons. For example, the outer one in the example below.

**How can I fix this, to get a smooth form?**

[image]

```
set.seed(0)
n <- 50
d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(n, -.7, .5), 
                y = rnorm(n, 0, .8))
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = ..level..), alpha=.1, geom = "polygon")
```

Comment: For the reproducible example you can do `scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-1.75, 0.5)) + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-2.0, 2.1))`. You just need to make sure the bounds of the chart are sufficient to avoid cropping the polygons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To build on @hrbrmstr's answer (which, at least on my machine, lops off one data point because the x scale isn't sufficiently wide), a slightly more involved approach would be to get the limits of the data, set the scale limits, then reset the plot limits back to the original range:

```
g <- ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = ..level..), alpha=.1, geom = "polygon")

dat_lims <- lapply(d, function(v) c(min(v), max(v)))
plot_lims <- ggplot_build(g)$panel$ranges[[1]][c("x.range", "y.range")]

g +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = dat_lims$x * 1.1) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = dat_lims$y * 1.1) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = plot_lims$x.range, ylim = plot_lims$y.range)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: that pretty much is what was said in _"You just need to make sure the bounds of the chart are sufficient to avoid cropping the polygons"_

Comment: @hrbrmstr -- right, agreed; hopefully my answer still added value by suggesting that you can afford to be much more generous in setting the scale limits, since you can always recover the original ranges through `coord_cartesian`.